# Spring MVC Adding external css to HTML

Tags: java, css, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I am having a major problem with paths in my Spring MVC project.
I have fixed so that I can see images/Css and so on in my jsp files, but my html files I am at a loss, I have tried all kinds of paths I can think of, but nothing seems to work... I hope anyone of you can help me find what I am doing wrong.

My spring config file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="controller" />
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<mvc:resources  mapping="/resources/**" location="resources/"></mvc:resources>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>

        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

My web xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                                         
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"    
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee           
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" 
version="3.0">

<display-name>Project By Robin Ejderholt</display-name>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
```

The css code im trying to fix:

```
<link href="/resources/css/menucss.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The current structure of my project:

[image: Project Structure]

Hope anyone can help because I got no clue why it doesn't work.

PS: I am using jstl on the jsp and that works, but what I am aware it is not possible on static html files.

Thanks

EDIT UPDATE:

I solved it, the solution for people with the same problem was to use the relative path; "../map/filename" instead of "/map/filename".

Comment: 1) Are you deploying to the root context? 2) Does the `link` live in the highlighted html file?

Comment: Try to move your html folder under /WEB-INF/ .

Comment: @DirkLachowski How do you see whether I do deploy it on root, sorry am quite the beginner. What do you mean by if the link live in the highlighted hml file, it is external css and in another folder

Comment: At 2) I was asking if you are trying to include the css in a static html file or in a jsp. If i understand your question right you have problems including a static css in an also static html. Am i right?

Comment: @DirkLachowski yes, thats correct, I get it to work in my jsp, but not in the static html files, like the about.html.